# Understanding equations representing time spent in certain Markov states

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

My notes on Markov chain long-term behaviour present the following definition:

> **Definition 10.**
>
> For any state $j$, define $N_j$ to be the number of times the Markov chain is at state $j$, excluding the initial state. Formally, $N_j = \# \{ n \ge 1 : X_n = j \}$.
>
> Note that $N_j$ takes the values in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \infty \}$.
>
> Note also that
>
> $$P(N_j = m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}(1 - f_{jj})$$
>
> and
>
> $$P(N_j \ge m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}.$$
>
> It follows that
>
> $$P(N_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ f_{jj} < 1, \\ f_{ij} & \text{if} \ f_{jj} = 1. \end{cases}$$
>
> So $P(N_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i) = 0$ if $j$ is transient, and $f_{ij}$ if $j$ is recurrent.

I have spent a significant amount of time reading over these notes (see below) to try and gain a good mathematical and intuitive understanding for the equations $P(N_j = m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}(1 - f_{jj})$, $P(N_j \ge m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}$, and $P(N_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ f_{jj} < 1, \\ f_{ij} & \text{if} \ f_{jj} = 1 \end{cases}$, but I am having great difficulty doing so. The way these concepts are explained in my notes make it very difficult for me to develop a clear understanding of this. For the first two equations in particular, I want to understand the presence of the terms in $f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}(1 - f_{jj})$ and $f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}$, as explained/introduced in the notes (see below).

The full notes are as follows:

> **Definition 7.**
>
> For a non-empty subset $A$ of the state space, define
>
> $$T_A = \min\{ n \ge 1 : X_n \in A \}.$$
>
> $T_A$ is called the hitting time of the time of first passage.
>
> If $X_n \not\in A$ for all $n \ge 1$, then $T_A = \infty$.
>
> For a state $i$, $T_{\{i\}}$ is written as $T_i$.
>
> **Theorem 10.**
>
> $$p^{(n)}_{ij} = \sum_{m = 1}^n P(T_j = m \vert X_0 = i) p^{(n - m)}_{jj}.$$
>
> **Definition 8.**
>
> For states $i$ and $j$, define
>
> $$f^{(n)}_{ij} = P(X_n = j, X_k \not= j, k = 1, 2, \dots, n - 1 \vert X_0 = i)$$
>
> and $f_{ij} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty f^{(n)}_{ij}$.
>
> In other words, $f^{(n)}_{ij}$ is the probability that, starting from state $i$, the first visit to $j$ occurs at the $n$th transition.
>
> $f^{(1)}_{ij} = p_{ij}$. And by convention, $f^{(0)}_{ij} = 0$, including for the case $i = j$.
>
> $f_{ij}$ is the same as $P(T_j < \infty \vert X_0 = i)$, and is the probability of the Markov chain reaching state $j$ some time if it starts from state $i$.
>
> Note that $P(T_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i)$ is $1 - f_{ij}$. In addition, $i$ leads to $j$ if and only if $f_{ij} > 0$.
>
> **Theorem 11.**
>
> $$p^{(n)}_{ii} = \sum_{k = 0}^n f_{ii}^{(k)}p^{(n - k)}_{ii}$$
>
> **Definition 9.** A state $i$ is said to be recurrent if $f_{ii} = 1$, and transient if $f_{ii} < 1$.
>
> If the state $i$ is recurrent, the probability that the Markov chain starting from $i$ returns to $i$ is $1$.
>
> If $i$ is transient, there is a positive probability that the chain, starting from $i$, will never return to $i$.
>
> All absorbing states are recurrent, because if $p_{ii} = 1$, then $f_{ii} = 1$.
>
> **Definition 10.**
>
> For any state $j$, define $N_j$ to be the number of times the Markov chain is at state $j$, excluding the initial state. Formally, $N_j = \# \{ n \ge 1 : X_n = j \}$.
>
> Note that $N_j$ takes the values in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \infty \}$.
>
> Note also that
>
> $$P(N_j = m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}(1 - f_{jj})$$
>
> and
>
> $$P(N_j \ge m \vert X_0 = i) = f_{ij} f_{jj}^{m - 1}.$$
>
> It follows that
>
> $$P(N_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ f_{jj} < 1, \\ f_{ij} & \text{if} \ f_{jj} = 1. \end{cases}$$
>
> So $P(N_j = \infty \vert X_0 = i) = 0$ if $j$ is transient, and $f_{ij}$ if $j$ is recurrent.

I was wondering if people would please take the time to explain these three equations, both mathematically and intuitively, so that the ideas conveyed by them are clear to me.

Comment: Is there a book associated with this?  It looks somewhat similar to a couple of the texts I have.  Since countable state markov chains interplay very nicely with basic countable/discerete renewal theory, it would be helpful (i.e. facilitate better explanations) to know whether you know some renewal theory

Comment: @user8675309 This is from some notes I was given; I am not aware of any textbook. I have never heard of "renewal theory".

Comment: Renewal theory is typically taught in a stochastics course that includes countable  markov chains (e.g. Ross's *Stochastic Processes* or about a third the MIT OCW course "Discrete Stochastic Processes" or classical but perhaps best: Feller vol 1).  When you say *"I have spent a significant amount of time... but I am having great difficulty... The way these concepts are explained in my notes make it very difficult"*  indicates you'd benefit from a detour into counting processes and renewal theory since $N_j = \lim_{t\to \infty}N_j(t)$ and $N_j(t)$ is the main object of study in renewal theory.

Comment: @user8675309 This sounds like it might be more technical than what I'm looking for. I'm more-so interested in an intuitive explanation for the equations -- something that clarifies and makes me think "ahh, I see", rather than a rigorous argument.

Comment: fair enough.  I am trying to decide whether there is a helpful but still concise answer here and if we sacrifice some rigor there may be one... incidentally the generator of all this is the 0-1 law (due to Polya I think) for random walks -- a state is visited with probability 1 **iff** the expected number of visits is infinite.

Comment: @user8675309 I think that a large part of my not feeling that I have a good grasp of what this is saying comes down to the presentation. Perhaps an explanation that puts everything together more clearly, cleanly, and coherently, with some further explanation of the equations themselves, rather than just copy-and-pasting theorems and equations, as is done in the notes, would help. [...]

Comment: [...] As for the concept you just alluded to, I think I am working with it as we speak: 1. If $S$ is finite and irreducible, then $P(T_j < \infty \vert X_0 = i) = 1$ for all $i, j \in S$; 2. If $S$ is finite, $j$ is the only absorbing state, and $p^{(n)}_{ij} > 0$ for some $n$, then $P(T_j < \infty \vert X_0 = i) = 1$; 3. The expected time to hit state $j$, starting in $i$, is $h_{ij} = E(T_j \vert X_0 = i)$. These are part of the notes that I am studying just now.

Answer (score 1):

- We begins from state $i$ and we want to visit state $j$ exactly $m$ times.

  1. Begining from state $i$, I have to be able to visit state $j$, that happens with probability $f_{ij}$, when that happens, that is the first visit. Probability in this step is $f_{ij}$
  2. Now starting from state $j$, we want to visit state $j$ for another $m-1$ times, the probability of each such occurence is $f_{jj}$, it has to happen $m-1$ times. Coresponding probability: $f_{jj}^{m-1}$
  3. After that, starting from state $j$, we want to compute the probability that it never visit state $j$ again. Corresponding probability: $1-f_{jj}$.

Multiplying them together

\begin{align}
P(N_j=m|X_0=i) = f_{ij}f_{jj}^{m-1}(1-f_{jj})
\end{align}

---

- We begins from state $i$ and we want to visit state $j$ at least $m$ times.

The argument is the same as earlier, that is

1. Begining from state $i$, I have to be able to visit state $j$, that happens with probability $f_{ij}$, when that happens, that is the first visit. Probability in this step is $f_{ij}$
2. Now starting from state $j$, we want to visit state $j$ for another $m-1$ times, the probability of each such occurence is $f_{jj}$, it has to happen $m-1$ times. Coresponding probability: $f_{jj}^{m-1}$
3. What happens next is irrelevant. We have achieved our goal of visiting $j$ at least $m$ times.

\begin{align}
P(N_j\ge m|X_0=i) = f_{ij}f_{jj}^{m-1}
\end{align}

---

- Given that $f_{jj}<1$, we want to show that $P(N_j = \infty|X_0=i)=0$.

We begins from state $i$, first we need to reach state $j$, and then we will visit state $j$ infinitely many times. However, if we are told that $f_{jj}<1$, then we know that $j$ is a transient state, hence after certain time, we will never visit state $j$ again, hence we can't have $N_j=\infty$.

A more mathematical claim is by taking the limit of the previous term:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty}P(N_j\ge m|X_0=i)=\lim_{m \to \infty}f_{ij}f_{jj}^{m-1}=f_{ij}\lim_{m \to \infty}f_{jj}^{m-1}=0$$

by geometric series.

---

- Given $f_{jj}=1$, we want to show that $P(N_j = \infty|X_0=i)=0$

We begin from state $i$, we need to visit state $j$, once we visit it, since state $j$ is a recurrence state, it will be visited infinitly often.

$$\lim_{m \to \infty}P(N_j\ge m|X_0=i)=\lim_{m \to \infty}f_{ij}f_{jj}^{m-1}=f_{ij}\lim_{m \to \infty}1^{m-1}=f_{ij}$$